# Apache Phoenix Create statement as select (from)

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

I am trying to create a new table from an existing structure in Phoenix. Is there a CREATE as Select statement in Phoenix. I am trying and they are failing with the below exception.

Any suggestions here are welcome. Thanks in advance.

```
 CREATE TABLE TEST AS (SELECT * FROM TEST_2 WHERE 1 =2);

org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 601 (42P00): Syntax error. Encountered "AS" at line 1, column 14.
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException.newException(PhoenixParserException.java:33)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:111)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$PhoenixStatementParser.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1280)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1363)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1434)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
Caused by: NoViableAltException(11@[])
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.from_table_name(PhoenixSQLParser.java:9564)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.create_table_node(PhoenixSQLParser.java:1096)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.oneStatement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:816)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.statement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:508)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:108)
        ... 9 more
CREATE TEST  (SELECT * FROM TEST_2 WHERE 1=2);
org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException: ERROR 601 (42P00): Syntax error. Encountered "SELECT" at line 1, column 34.
        at org.apache.phoenix.exception.PhoenixParserException.newException(PhoenixParserException.java:33)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:111)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement$PhoenixStatementParser.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1280)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.parseStatement(PhoenixStatement.java:1363)
        at org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixStatement.execute(PhoenixStatement.java:1434)
        at sqlline.Commands.execute(Commands.java:822)
        at sqlline.Commands.sql(Commands.java:732)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.dispatch(SqlLine.java:808)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.begin(SqlLine.java:681)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.start(SqlLine.java:398)
        at sqlline.SqlLine.main(SqlLine.java:292)
Caused by: NoViableAltException(133@[])
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.column_name(PhoenixSQLParser.java:2553)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.column_def(PhoenixSQLParser.java:3934)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.column_defs(PhoenixSQLParser.java:3858)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.create_table_node(PhoenixSQLParser.java:1104)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.oneStatement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:816)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.PhoenixSQLParser.statement(PhoenixSQLParser.java:508)
        at org.apache.phoenix.parse.SQLParser.parseStatement(SQLParser.java:108)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** do like this in `Phoenix`.

Instead you need to create a **view** of a **existing Hbase/Phoenix** table first which in your case is '`test_2`'

So you can do something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW test_view (a VARCHAR, b VARCHAR) AS
SELECT * FROM test_2
WHERE 1 = 2 ;  // some condition
```

For more information refer here : [Phoenix](https://phoenix.apache.org/views.html)